# For more explanation about the difference between the following equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractions, differential, differential-operators, fractional-calculus

Can someone tell me the  difference between the two following initial value problems :

$$
\begin{array}{l}
D^\alpha x(t)=f(t,x(t)) \\
x(0)=x_0
\end{array} \tag 1
$$

$$
\begin{array}{l}
D^\alpha (x(t)-x_0)=f(t,x(t)) \\
x(0)=x_0
\end{array} \tag 2
$$

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, because
$$D^{\alpha}(x(t)-x_0)=D^{\alpha}x(t)-D^{\alpha}x_0=D^{\alpha}x(t)$$